# Automated testing for Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

Hitting a couple of issues attempting to setup automated testing of our C++ code on Windows Phone 8.

1)  I'm hitting the limit of installed applications on our device.  Is there any way to automate uninstalling the applications on the device?  Via the command line?

2)  Is there a recommended method to run unit tests on WinPhone8?  Currently, I'm using devenv to load/run the  our solution file.  This has provided inconsistent results.  The Windows Phone debugger doesn't get set in some cases, this causing a 'debugger not set' error when attempting to run.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for starting win8 app from command line ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is some good information on unit testing in Windows Phone 8:

http://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?from=&to=en&a=http://qmatteoq.com/blog/post/unit-testing-in-windows-phone-8-the-basics

http://wp.qmatteoq.com/unit-testing-in-windows-phone-8-asynchronous-operations-and-mocking/

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Our code is in C++, plus we have our own internal unit test framework.  Really, I need a method of starting the unit tests from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

JustinAngel's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13429709/2087252 gives an example how to automate installing, running and deleting of applications on Windows Phone 8.

To make it work you'll need to reference following dlls from your project:

- Microsoft.Smartdevice.Connectivity.Interface.dll
- Microsoft.Smartdevice.Connectivity.dll
- Microsoft.Smartdevice.MultiTargeting.Connectivity.dll

If you want to run your application/test on emulator, you can start it with following command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\8.0\xde.exe" /name "Emulator WVGA 512MB.username"
```

where `username` is your windows username.