# How to deploy Apps in Windows Phone 8 Emulator for testing without having vs2012 installed in windows 8 machine?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

hi i am developing a windows phone 8 app , i have following doubts :-

How to deploy Apps in  Windows Phone 8 Emulator  for testing without having vs2012 installed in windows 8 machine,

since i cannot have a licensed version of vs2012 in my tester machine since  i want to it use for descent amount of time , i.e more than 1 month or 3 months(not trail versions)

1) Can i Open Windows Phone 8  Emulator via Command Line with having vs2012 installed  my  tester windows 8 machine.

2) Will Application Deployment Tool Will Be available to deploy apps in emulator  without Having vs2012 installed in my  tester windows 8 machine.

3)Any Alternative of deploying apps into windows phone 8 emulator without having vs2012 installed in the machine.??/

Thanks in Adavnce.

Comment: How do you develop WP8 app w/o VS2012 installed?

Comment: Figured out - there is second test machine.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Install Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone - it is free

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-phone

Answer (score 1):

1) You can start emulator with following command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\8.0\xde.exe" /name "Emulator WVGA 512MB.username"
```

where `username` is your windows username.

2 & 3) You can deploy/run/delete apps using solution described in JustinAngel's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13429709/2087252 .

To make it work you'll need to reference following dlls from your project:

```
Microsoft.Smartdevice.Connectivity.Interface.dll
Microsoft.Smartdevice.Connectivity.dll
Microsoft.Smartdevice.MultiTargeting.Connectivity.dll
```