# Multiple WindowsPhone Devices on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows-phone-7, deployment, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How can i use multiple WP device in Visual Studio? I need to test an application on multiple devices at the same time, how can I do? I do not need to start debugging on both, I just need to be able to deploy on both phones. One is WP8 and the other WP7. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, you can't automate deployment to multiple devices using Visual Studio, DeployXap or CoreCon11 APIs. The way Visual Studio 2012 and DeployXap.exe do their thing is by using the CoreCon11 APIs (which I demoed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420733/connect-to-windows-phone-8-using-console-application/13429709#13429709) and explained [here](http://justinangel.net/WindowsPhone7EmulatorAutomation)). However, the way CoreCon11 APIs work is that they only recognize one physical connected device at a time and one version of each emulator. Here's a print out of all available devices on a machine with 2 WP8s connected to it:

[image: Devices]

As you can see, there's only one "device" available from the CoreCon11 APIs. Because CoreCon11 APIs only support deployment to a single device, you can't automate those APIs or anything using them to deploy to multiple devices.

It might be possible to change how the CoreCon11 DataStore PlatformContainer works and add additional devices, but I don't have a code sample to share.

Comment: I solved it by creating a program that compiles only on WP7 devices and another one that compiles only on WP8 devices!
i've used this code:

[code]
foreach (Platform p in dataStoreManager.GetPlatforms())
                if (p.Name.Equals("Windows Phone 7"))
                {
                    platformWP7 = p;
                    break;
                }
[/code]
 Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy to the first phone by connecting it and selecting `Deploy` from the `Build` menu. You can then disconnect the first device, connect the second device and debug as per usual.