# UI Testing and automation on Windows Phone 8

Tags: .net, testing, windows-phone-8, ui-automation

Can I run UI automated testing on a Windows Phone 8 emulator? So far all the answers and articles I could find  refer to Windows Phone 7 platform.

Are there any Microsoft tools or perhaps some third party libraries that address this issue?
Can I do this on the emulator without an actual device?

Comment: Hi @CodinRonin welcome to SO! Questions asking for "the best" are often closed, so I've edited yours a bit to fit our style - now it is an answerable question. You can edit it yourself more if you want to.

Comment: Thanks Kate. I'll mind this in the future.

Comment: An answer about WP8 from the author of an article on WP7 automation is provided in [connect to windows phone 8 using console application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420733/connect-to-windows-phone-8-using-console-application)

Comment: this may be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544730/ui-automation-in-windows-phone-8-application

Comment: You can take a look at https://github.com/2gis/winphonedriver project. It is Windows Phone Driver for Selenium.

Answer (score 2):

Coded UI now supports UI automated tests for  Windows phone 8. It can be run in emulator, so you won't need an actual device.

To start with Coded UI tests for WP in your solution select `File->Add->New project...`
In the `Add New Project` dialog select `Coded UI Test Project (Windows Phone)` under `Visual C#`->`Windows phone Apps` node

Here is a link to *Automated Testing of XAML-Based Apps for Windows and Windows Phone* session by Prachi Bora
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/3-593

Session summary:

> Do you want to create automated tests for your apps? With Visual
>   Studio 2013 Update 2 you can now create automated tests for your
>   XAML-based Windows and Windows Phone apps. Starting from unit tests to
>   functional end-to-end scenario tests using coded UI tests, you can now
>   perform all of your testing from the integrated Test Explorer in
>   Visual Studio. The testing framework is extensible and developers can
>   customize it to meet the specialized needs of their application. In
>   this session, we will show you how to build comprehensive test suites
>   for your apps by leveraging these Visual Studio capabilities that will
>   help you ship a great quality app.

Comment: How are you? I have appx file only.Can i automate it without any source code? Could you please provide a example of it? Thanks.

Comment: Hello. You can find example of preinstalled Calendar app automation using Winium.StoreApps.CodedUI at https://github.com/2gis/Winium.StoreApps.CodedUi/blob/master/TestExamples/test_sample.py
Note that Winium.StoreApps.CodedUI is proof of concept and not production ready.
You can try using coded UI directly, here is a link to MS blog https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn747198.aspx