# UI automation in windows phone 8 application

Tags: testing, windows-phone-8, ui-automation

i have searched for automating UI in windows phone 8 applications and i did not get any useful tool or framework for that so is there any framework to automate UI application in windows phone 8?

Comment: What do you mean by automation? Do yo mean writing code that runs itself? Do you mean animation? Can you provide a little more info.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Winium.

> Why Winium?

- > You have Selenium WebDriver for testing of web apps, Appium for
  >   testing of iOS and Android apps. And now you have Selenium-based
  >   tools for testing of Windows apps too. What are some of the benefits? 
  >   As said by Appium:
- > You can write tests with your favorite dev tools using any
  >   WebDriver-compatible language such as **Java, Objective-C, JavaScript
  >   with Node.js (in promise, callback or generator flavors), PHP, Python,
  >   Ruby, C#, Clojure**, or Perl with the Selenium WebDriver API and
  >   language-specific client libraries.
- > You can use any testing framework.

> How it works?
>
> Winium.StoreApps consists of two essential parts:

1. > **Winium.StoreApps.Driver** implements Selenium Remote WebDriver and
   >   listens for JsonWireProtocol commands. It is responsible for launching
   >   emulator, deploying AUT, simulating input, forwarding commands to
   >   Winium.StoreApps.InnerServer, etc.
2. > **Winium.StoreApps.InnerServer** (the one that should be embedded into
   >   AUT) communicates with Winium.StoreApps.Driver.exe and executes
   >   different commands, like finding elements, getting or setting text
   >   values, properties, etc., inside your application.

[image]

> Test samples:

**`Python`**

```
# coding: utf-8
import unittest

from selenium.webdriver import Remote


class TestMainPage(unittest.TestCase):
desired_capabilities = {
      "app": "C:\\YorAppUnderTest.appx"
  }

  def setUp(self):
      self.driver = Remote(command_executor="http://localhost:9999",
                         desired_capabilities=self.desired_capabilities)

  def test_button_tap_should_set_textbox_content(self):
      self.driver.find_element_by_id('SetButton').click()
      assert 'CARAMBA' == self.driver.find_element_by_id('MyTextBox').text

  def tearDown(self):
      self.driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
unittest.main()

Please check the link below. It can help you a lot.

You just have to follow guidance in this project.
```

**`C#`**

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;

[TestFixture]
public class TestMainPage
{
  public RemoteWebDriver Driver { get; set; }

  [SetUp]
  public void SetUp()
  {
      var dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
      dc.SetCapability("app", "C:\\YorAppUnderTest.appx");
      this.Driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:9999"), dc);
  }

  [Test]
  public void TestButtonTapShouldSetTextboxContent()
  {
      this.Driver.FindElementById("SetButton").Click();
      Assert.IsTrue("CARAMBA" ==       this.Driver.FindElementById("MyTextBox").Text);
  }

  [TearDown]
  public void TearDown()
  {
      this.Driver.Quit();
  }
}
```

[Winium.StoreApps](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.StoreApps)

I am currently working on a Windows Phone Automation using this opensource

project, it works pretty well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this project: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Simple-UI-Test-for-Windows-dc0573a9

It shows how to simulate clicking on a button and retrieving the value of another element.

I haven't tried this myself, but the principle seems to be:

Create a separate test project

In your test initialization code, instantiate a page from your app project:

```
public void Init() 
{                
    mp1 = new PhoneApp1.MainPage(); 
}
```

Your tests find elements by referring to that instantiated page:

```
[TestMethod] 
[Description("Test1:  Clicking button passes")] 
public void PassedTest() 
{ 
    var b = mp1.FindName("button1") as Button; 
    ButtonAutomationPeer peer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(b); 
    IInvokeProvider invokeProv = peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider; 
    invokeProv.Invoke();                          
    Assert.AreEqual((mp1.FindName("AppTitle") as TextBlock).Text.ToString(), "Results"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently investigating CodedUI tests because they may be the solution.
Here is the official statement from the Microsoft Application Lifecycle Management blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/05/using-coded-ui-to-test-xaml-based-windows-phone-apps.aspx

There are some very specific details in the article that I would like to highlight:

- You require to have at least Visual Studio 2013 Update 2
- Quoting the article:

> WebView control used to host HTML content in a XAML app is currently
>   not supported.

- Also

  > You can also interact with Shell controls – controls that are not
  >   XAML, but essential for testing your app E2E – such as the tiles,
  >   confirmation dialogs, etc. These controls are provided by the OS and
  >   are not XAML.
- The final limitation mentioned:

> Only XAML based store apps are supported. Silverlight and HTML 5 based
>   apps cannot be tested using Coded UI.

I will update my reply whenever I have gained some practice with CodedUI for Windows Phone 8 apps - I need to write the tests myself and run them on an actual device.