# How to deploy an .appx into Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, connectivity, smart-device-framework

I use the Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity to connect to Windows Phone 8.1 OS with the instruction in this link: [connect to windows phone 8 using console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420733/connect-to-windows-phone-8-using-console-application) 
Now I can connect to both Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator or Windows Phone 8.1 Device, and I can launch any application by using their ProductID. 
So now I would like to install my apps which I developed to these device by using this framework. I know that the XAP package for WP8.1 is an .appx file. To install 1 apps in this framework I use the InstallApplication() method like this:

```
 IRemoteApplication remoteApplication = iDevice.InstallApplication(appID, appID, applicationGenre, iconPath, xapPackage);
```

Which appID is the ProductID, I got it in the Package.appxmanifest page is: 
`556ee9d4-5640-4120-9916-44b1ca27352f`
But I got the exception is:

```
"An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.SmartDeviceException' occurred in Microsoft.Smartdevice.Connectivity.dll

Additional information: An attempt was made to move the file pointer before the beginning of the file."
```

When I use the Application Deployment tool provided by Visual Studio, this app can be installed, but when I use connectivity framework, I can't install it.
So how can I install this app by using Connectivity Framework?
 Please help me. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, AFAIK v11 of SmartDevice.Connectivity won't be able to deploy APPX. You'll need V12 to deploy APPX. The APIs are so different even the tool to deploy WP8.1 APPX is a different tool then the one to deploy WP7-WP8.0 XAPs.

[image: XAP deployment tool vs. 8.1 APPX deployment tool]

Anyway, you can deploy a Windows Phone 8.1 APPX using this C# code:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // step #1: Add refrences. 
    // - Add DLL reference to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Tools\AppDeploy\Microsoft.Phone.Tools.Deploy.dll
    // GAC references are implicit on computers with VS2013/VS2014 installed alongside WP8.1 dev tools. 
    // - GAC reference to: Microsoft.Phone.Tools.Common, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
    // - GAC reference to: Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.Interface, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
    // - GAC reference to: Microsoft.SmartDevice.MultiTargeting.Connectivity, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

    try
    {
        // Step #2: Get devices
        var devices = Utils.GetDevices();

        Console.WriteLine("Possible Devices for deployment: ");
        foreach (var deviceInfo in devices)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + deviceInfo.ToString());
        }

        // Step #3: choose a device
        var device = devices.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ToString() == "Emulator 8.1 1080P 6 inch");

        if (device == null)
            return;
        Console.WriteLine("Using device: " + device.ToString());


        // step #4: Select XAP, DeploymentOptions and Manifest
        string appxFileUri = @"D:\Users\Justin Angel\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\App15\App15\AppPackages\App15_1.1.0.0_AnyCPU_Test\App15_1.1.0.0_AnyCPU.appx";
        IAppManifestInfo manifestInfo = Utils.ReadAppManifestInfoFromPackage(appxFileUri); ;
        DeploymentOptions deploymentOptions = DeploymentOptions.None;

        // Step #5: deploy
        Console.WriteLine("Attempting to deploy: " + manifestInfo.Name + " from " + appxFileUri);
        Utils.InstallApplication(device, manifestInfo, deploymentOptions, appxFileUri);
        Console.WriteLine("deployed successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to deploy");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

When I try to run this the APPX is successfully deployed on my machine everything works fine and the app is installed as expected.

[image: Foo Bar Baz Test app successfully installs]

If you want to get fancier with Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator/Device automation (install on SD card, delete, enterprise installation, etc), you can play around with different DeploymentOptions:

```cs
namespace Microsoft.Phone.Tools.Deploy
{
  [Flags]
  public enum DeploymentOptions
  {
    None = 0,
    PA = 1,
    Debug = 2,
    Infused = 4,
    Lightup = 8,
    Enterprise = 16,
    Sideload = 32,
    TypeMask = 255,
    UninstallDisabled = 256,
    SkipUpdateAppInForeground = 512,
    DeleteXap = 1024,
    InstallOnSD = 65536,
    OptOutSD = 131072,
  }
}
```

[image: Works on my machine]

Comment: If you need a simple deployment (with less options) then the command line AppDeployCmd ships with wp8.1 SDK tools and works really well - easy to automate. It also can be decompiled using dotpeek or reflector if you need hints about how the multidevice.connectivity assembly is designed to be used.

Comment: Is there a way to deploy the appx to an already running Emulator?