# Create Windows Phone 8.1 app package with makeappx.exe

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, appx

I have Windows Phone 8.1 project (not Silverlight).
I want create app package using makeappx.exe without Visual Studio. Using command

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64>makeappx.exe pack /v /l 
/d C:\MyAppProjectFolder\
/p C:\MyAppProjectFolder\MyApp.appx
```

But had errors:

```
MakeAppx : error: You must include a valid app package manifest file named AppxManifest.xml in the source.
MakeAppx : error: Package creation failed.
MakeAppx : error: 0x80080203 - The specified package format is not valid: The file is not a valid app package because it
```

The project doesn't contains `AppxManifest.xml` file. But contains `Package.appxmanifest` file. I must create `AppxManifest.xml` mannualy?
I can't find information about this in MSDN pages.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to copy `Package.appxmanifest`, rename to `AppxManifest` and replace this:

```
<Application Id="App"
          Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
          EntryPoint="YourAppName.App">
```

to this:

```
<Application Id="App"
             Executable="bin\debug\YourAppName.exe"
             EntryPoint="YourAppName.App">
```

You can also generate an Appx by building you Project with `MSBuild`, according the answer to **[How to deploy APPX to running Windows Phone Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756989/how-to-deploy-appx-to-running-windows-phone-emulator/33903473#33903473)**.

It worked for me, but I'm trying to find somethig better, if I do, I'll edit this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manually create an appx package then yes you'll need to create the `AppxManifest.xml` manually. Visual studio normally uses the information in your `Package.appxmanifest` to create the `AppxManifest.xml` for you.

[MSDN: How to create a basic package manifest for Windows 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/br211475.aspx) (it's valid for 8.1 appx)

You may also need to create a `resources.pri` (with makepri.exe) and a mapping file that tells `makeappx.exe` what files to include in what paths in the package, depending on how you go about it.